# No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA always popup picture selections

Tags: java, spring, recaptcha

I have implemented google No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA in my spring web application.When ever i click check box it always shows pop up of picture selection.This not only once every time when i click check box it pops picture selection.

Is this right working of recapctha.

Please give me some reason why it is happening like this.is there issue with my working code or what might be the reason .Please help me on this.

Comment: It could be that when your testing it and using it a lot, it will start to show the pictures more often.

Comment: @Ryan89 Might be, but there should be some reason for that,like is it for browser or plugins?